# How to find all the triples in a graph?

Tags: igraph

The graph consists of more than three million nodes and more than 20 million edges. I'm using igraph package on a 8G RAM linux server. The code is

```
cliques(g,min=3,max=3)
```

After six days passed, the code is still running. Is there a better way to find all the triples in a graph?

Comment: Yeah, R is not the best tool for handling such a huge graph (R is famous non-optimal memory handling with these structures). If I were you, I'd give a try to Pajek, it's main goal is to deal with those huge graphs. It has a bit sophisticated UI, but once you get familiar with it simply works.

Comment: @rlegendi: the code of `cliques` is not implemented in R, but in C, including the memory management.

Comment: I would first estimate the number of triangles, because it can be huge. Call `triad.census()`, maybe not the graph itself first, but part of it. If it is feasible to list all triangles, then use the development build from http://igraph.org/nightly and the `triangles()` function.

Comment: @GaborCsardi Oh, sry, now I recall only the interface is exposed to R... Back a while I had to play around with the source code a bit. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @GaborCsardi Two questions: (1) Graph in function triad.census() should be directed. But the graph I used is undirected. How should I estimate the number of triangles? (2) Why should I estimate the number of triangles? To list all triangles, let's say ten million triangles, is it that difficult to store all the triangles?

Comment: (1) convert it to directed with `as.directed()`. (2) because you might have a billion triangles, and these might take some time to list. Depends on your graph. But if you want to go ahead and list them, then do that. Super simple with the dev version of igraph.

Answer (score 1):

Following @GaborCsardi suggestion you can see this simple example (I used http://igraph.org/nightly igraph dev version)

```
kite <- graph.famous("Krackhardt_Kite")
triangles(kite)
```

which yields:

[1] 4 1 2 4 1 3 4 2 5 4 6 1 4 6 3 4 6 7 4 7 2 4 7 5 6 1 3 6 7 8 7 2 5

for the (undirected) graph "Krackhardt_Kite"

You can compare the results with

`plot(kite)`

Hope this helps

Comment: A way to convert this to a data frame:

```kite.triangles = triangles(kite)
kite.triangles.df = data.frame(node1=as.vector(kite.triangles[seq(1, length(kite.triangles), 3)]), node1=as.vector(kite.triangles[seq(2, length(kite.triangles), 3)]), node1=as.vector(kite.triangles[seq(3, length(kite.triangles), 3)]))
   node1 node1.1 node1.2
1      4       1       2
2      4       1       3
3      4       2       5
4      4       6       1
5      4       6       3
6      4       6       7
7      4       7       2
8      4       7       5
9      6       1       3```